# Creating secure architecture and payout process

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, payment, server

I studied lots of valuable q&a here, but still I have some doubts.

Case - simple game (calm down - I'm not one of the rookies creating exchange as seen here), which allows to pay for a game. The character of the gameplay forces us to create virtual balance for each player and create payouts on daily basis/request.

What's done:

- compiled bitcoind client is running on encrypted wallet in background
- creating in advance pool of addresses
- assigning free address to registered user
- listen for incoming transactions/confirmations
- on 6th confirmation we add transaction to user balance

Where I need guidance / pro advice:

- strip my runnning bitcoind client with wallet from holding private keys (I've read about it but don't know how to achieve it properly)
- many guides advice to run bitcoind client on other machine - but how to setup secure communication between two machines (vpn?), if someone gains access to game server, it doesn't matter where client is located (right?)
- as private keys are stored away, how I can deal with payout requests? Are there known practices in that field? I've read https://bitcoinsecurityproject.org/SecureApplicationArchitecture/, but can't imagine real world example/process

Last but not least - if users send coins to private addresses created in one wallet, which private key should sign a transaction? As you probably see, I'm confused with some "basics" after research here :)

**EDIT**

I found steps to sign transaction offline (http://people.xiph.org/~greg/signdemo.txt) is it preferable way in real world apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to  be doing some fun stuff if you need a complex system.

**The Simple Way**

Just use Bitcoind along with it's `walletnotify` and `blocknotify` arguments. [See here.](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=203438.0) As soon as you get a walletnotify, store it in a database and make sure txid is unique. **Walletnotify fires multiple times** throughout a transaction's life. Check the database every block looking for unprocessed transactions that have 6 confirms. Those that do should get marked as "processed" or get deleted from the database.

**The Hardcore Way**

If you need the functionality like described. Consider using one of the many libraries that implement some Bitcoin features and function. Check out [Bitcoinj](https://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/) (java), [Libbitcoin](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=30646.0) (C++), [Gocoin](https://github.com/piotrnar/gocoin) (Go), and the [many python libraries](https://github.com/search?l=Python&o=desc&q=bitcoin%20library&ref=searchresults&s=stars&type=Repositories) that can be found through search. These libraries can make it a lot more simple to run a more finely controlled and specialized node.

Comment: Thanks for the input, we already done incoming payments. I have biggest doubts when it comes to payouts where high security is a must...

Comment: My bad, but payouts are hard to game on the Bitcoin side, once you push your transaction it's a done deal. But watch out for stuff like race conditions where a user can send you hundreds of requests in the a small time frame. Make sure your database and code process these atomically.